How can I add a border between title bar and text area
How can I add a border between the title bar and the text area
I figured how to do it between the sidebar and text area but i can’t figure this one out
Image of what I want
So for my sidebar I used something like this
{
    "class": "sidebar_container",
    "layer1.tint": "hsl(216, 10%, 20%)",
    "layer1.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer1.inner_margin": [0, 0, 6, 0],
    "layer1.draw_center": false
}

to add border right
But I can't figure out how to do it for the title bar I tried to add something like that for the "edit_window" class but it didn't work.
